# Can one use a contraction in a question?

Tags: questions, contractions

> a) Why are you trying so hard?
>
> b) Why you're trying so hard?

Is *you're* (b) an acceptable contraction form of *are you* (a) when I want to keep the sentence in a question form?

Is there another way to contract (this) question in English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can indeed use a contraction in  question:

> Why don't you do it today?

But "you're" is a contraction of "you are" not of "are you " so it does not work in sentence b) from the question, which expands to:

> Why you are trying so hard?

which is not really grammatical, and certainly does not carry the same meaning as sentence a).

"you're" can be used in a question in any case that "you are" can be. For example:

> You're not going to leave early, are you?

Answer (score 1):

you're is generally a contraction of "you are", so saying "why you are trying so hard?" would not sound totally correct in this instance. In general though there's no particular reason to not use a contraction in a question.

However, if formulated slightly differently it would sound idiomatic. Consider "You have to ask yourself why you're trying so hard".